# Select entire row of data as a record in the format of NEW in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, plpgsql, record

I have a trigger that compares a newly inserted row to a previous one. I take the NEW parameter from the trigger and would like to compare this to the previous row that has some of the same values as the inserted row. So I use the following command to find the related record object:

```
 execute 'SELECT * from table where field1=''' || new_entry.field1 || ''' and field2=''' ||
        new_entry.field2 || ''' and id < ' || new_entry.id || ' order by id DESC limit 1' into target;
```

Here new_entry is the NEW object. I would think that this command return the same as the NEW object but they don't. Instead it adds some "" to the jsonb objects inside. Here are the comparison of the NEW object to the previous record from the command above:

OLD entry: `("(326,""2019-09-24 02:18:52.848206+00"",/somevalue/,null,7,""{""""abc"""": {""""abcd""""`

NEW entry: `(353,"2019-09-25 09:20:34.088914+00",/somevalue/,null,7,"{""abc"": {""abcd"":`

EDIT: I also tried format like this:

```
 SELECT format ('SELECT * INTO %I FROM table WHERE field1=%L and field=%L and id < %L ORDER BY id DESC limit 1', 'target', new_entry.field1, new_entry.field2, new_entry.id )
```

The result is this: OLD entry : ()

Comment: Note:there is a `format()` function.

Comment: @wildplasser Tried it couldn't get it to get any data with format.

Comment: From The Fine Manual; `... since this form of SELECT INTO is not available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the INTO clause differently....`

Comment: What type is `target`? On my system the above works perfectly fine, as long as `target` is a variable of the table type. It's not adding quotes to your json per se, btw. Look at the start: `("(326` - your row is inside another row, therefore all special values are escaped, so quotes are double quoted etc. And I don't see the need for dynamic sql here. `SELECT * INTO target FROM table WHERE field1 = new_entry.field1` should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @404 target is of type record. I need it in this type since NEW is in this type. Any way I can get it as a record type?

Comment: @404 yeah fixing it to table works thanks buddy!